# Failed to execute goal maven maven-antrun-plugin:1.7 on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException around Ant part hadoop-hdfsproject hadoop-hdfs:?

Tags: windows, hadoop, build, hdfs, bigdata

I'm trying to build the following hadoop version on development computer with Windows 10 Home Edition

hadoop-2.7.3-src

Here are the details about my local development environment:

-Windows 10 Home Edition

-Intel Core i5-6200U CPU @2.30GHz

-RAM 16 GB

-64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

-Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

-.NET Framework 4.6.01586

-cmake version 3.7.2

-CYGWIN_NT-10.0 LTPBCV82DUG 2.7.0(0.306/5/3) 2017-02-12 13:18 x86_64 Cygwin

-java version "1.8.0_121"

-Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

-Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

-Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)

-Google Protocol Buffers   protoc --version  libprotoc 2.5.0

I opened up Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2015 (VS2015)

c:\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.3-src>  mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar -X

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:27 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-15T19:26:50-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 102M/1591M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.3-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 8:126 in C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.3-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.3-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 8:126 in C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.3-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.3-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 8:126 in C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.3-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.3-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml:8: exec returned: 1
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:327)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-hdfs
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on CentOS 7.2 while hadoop-common was building
Was gone after I did
sudo yum -y install zlib
sudo yum -y install zlib-devel

after I got another one in hadoop-pipes module, I did
sudo yum -y install -y openssl-devel

and succeed with my build.

Hope it will be useful.